# BOX oauth2 in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build a simple extension for box.com in Chrome. Everything is fine until Box returns the token to the extension and I got this

> Denying load of chrome-extension://finiioneilhchmigihgjmjbaopjjeggo/authentication.html?state=authenticated&code=Epmau2e0WZKFYojl2FpH9Kux39nVs82V. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Its obvious that I need to list the file authentication.html in web_accessible_resources manifest key. I did both

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["chrome-extension://finiioneilhchmigihgjmjbaopjjeggo/authentication.html"],
```

(`finiioneilhchmigihgjmjbaopjjeggo` is my app's id btw) and

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["authentication.html"],
```

but neither of them work. What should I do to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try making the resource name exactly match the request, including the query parameters? Of course you won't be able to hardcode that, but at least you'll confirm that web_accessible_resources is behaving as you expect.

Comment: @sowbug I did, I run the same query on my local host web app, it performs normally.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not 'clean' and/or the way it should be done but changing the manifest_version to 1 worked for me. It's just a *workaround* :-(

Comment: When working with version 2 manifest file, do not forget to add the [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) section to whitelist the resources